# How to get option_id of an option by label? (magento 2)

Tags: magento2, attributes, attribute-options

I want to get the option_id of one of the options on an attribute, but I only know the label of the option (by label, I mean the 'value' column in `eav_attribute_option_value`).

How can I get it?

Right now I have the following code:

```
/**  @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository $productAttributeRepository */

$options = $productAttributeRepository->get('treadwidth')->getOptions();

foreach ($options as $option) {
    var_dump($option->getValue());  // option_id
    var_dump($option->getLabel());  // value
}
```

In other words, it is possible for me to loop through each option and check if the `option_id` matches the one I want, but I wan't to do this directly. Is it possible?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I've run into the same issue..

Answer (score 3):

If you have the attribute, you can do this:

```
 $id = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionId($label);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a function to check optionId find (or exist). You may check it below.

```
function getOptionId(\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute $attribute, string $label)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $attribute */
    $attributeFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute');
    $attributeValues=array();

    $attributeValues[$attribute->getAttributeId()] = [];
    /** @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table $sourceModel */
    $sourceModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table');
    $sourceModel->setAttribute($attribute);

    foreach ($sourceModel->getAllOptions() as $option) {
        $attributeValues[ $attribute->getAttributeId() ][ $option['label'] ] = $option['value'];
    }
    if (isset($attributeValues[ $attribute->getAttributeId() ][ $label ])) {
        return $attributeValues[ $attribute->getAttributeId() ][ $label ];
    }

    // Return false if does not exist
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php 
protected $productAttributeRepository;

public function __construct(
ContextInterface $context,
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository $productAttributeRepository
) {
$this->productAttributeRepository = $productAttributeRepository;
parent::__construct($context);
}

$options = $this->productAttributeRepository->get('brand')->getOptions();

foreach ($options as $option) {
    var_dump($option->getValue());  // option_id
    var_dump($option->getLabel());  // value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"To get option label by Id"

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    /** @var \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeOptionManagementInterface $attributeOptions */

    $attributeOptionsManagement = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeOptionManagementInterface::class);

    /** @var \Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionInterface[] $attributeOptions */

    $attributeOptions = $attributeOptionsManagement->getItems(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE, 'feature_products');
    $featuredOptions = [];
    foreach ($attributeOptions as $attributeOption) {
    $featuredOptions[$attributeOption->getValue()] = $block->escapeHtml($attributeOption->getLabel());
    }
echo $featuredOptions['option_id']
```